# Creating a sparse matrix from a dataframe with edges

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a csv file containining data in the following format:

A B

C D

A C

D F

G H

K M

M A

where each row gives an undirected edge between node1 and node2.  I'm currently reading this in as a dataframe, but would like to convert it to a sparse matrix.  Is there a quick and easy way to do this without looping?

Answer (score 0):

To construct a scipy sparse matrix directly you have to map the letters onto unique indices, e.g. `A == 1`, `B == 2`, etc

```
In [202]: txt='''A B
     ...: 
     ...: C D
     ...: 
     ...: A C
     ...: 
     ...: D F
     ...: 
     ...: G H
     ...: 
     ...: K M
     ...: 
     ...: M A'''.splitlines()
In [203]: values = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
In [204]: data = [x.split() for x in txt if x]
In [205]: data = [[values.index(x) for x in row] for row in data]
In [206]: data
Out[206]: [[0, 1], [2, 3], [0, 2], [3, 5], [6, 7], [10, 12], [12, 0]]
```

So now we have coordinate pairs.  There are various ways of constructing a sparse matrix from these.  Perhaps the simplest, conceptually, is to do it iteratively with an `lil` format matrix (the best format for iterative construction):

```
In [207]: from scipy import sparse
In [208]: M = sparse.lil_matrix((len(values),len(values)),dtype=int)
In [209]: for row in data:
     ...:     M[tuple(row)] = 1
     ...:     
In [210]: M
Out[210]: 
<13x13 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [211]: M.A
Out[211]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```